# SLD GeoServer : impossible to use attributes to set scales?

Tags: geoserver, fields-attributes, style

We are currently using a GeoServer 2.17.5 and creating Style Encoding styles.

I'm looking for set the `MinScaleDenominator`, `MaxScaleDenominator` and stroke color from the layer attributes. The scales attributes are integer datatype while the color attribute is text datatype.

Using this for the stroke works perfectly :

```xml
          <se:LineSymbolizer>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:PropertyName>color</ogc:PropertyName>
              </se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">2.0</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-opacity">1.0</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:LineSymbolizer>
```

But using this for the scales :

```xml
          <se:MinScaleDenominator>
            <ogc:PropertyName>scale_min</ogc:PropertyName>
          </se:MinScaleDenominator>
```

Always lead to rise a java error : `java.lang.RuntimeException: Parsing failed for MinScaleDenominator: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String`

Of course : all rows in the table have values.

I also tried to format the integer values to string but I did not found any suitable function to do this on https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#filter-function-reference.

So : what is the trick ?

Comment: > The SLD specification does not allow for expressions in scale denominators Thank you for your answer.
So end of the game. I report this in our documentation. I saw the capacity to build my own functions but it is not suitable to my use case. Thanks.

Comment: You don't have to build new functions, the "env" one is there, available and should be working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The SLD specification does not allow for expressions in scale denominators.

However, GeoServer provides the current scale also an "environment variable", which you can then use in filters through the "env" function.

See examples here:

https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/substitution.html#predefined-variables

A rough (untested) filter could look like:

```xml
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:Function name="env"><ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal></ogc:Function>
              <ogc:PropertyName>scale_min</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
          </ogc:Filter>
```